# What does "crime bill" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I read [a discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/526271/319998) and see the word "**crime bill**", can I ask what does it mean?

> Suppose a **crime bill** was passed in 2016 and the number of visible
> police on patrol doubled. The goal of the legislation was to reduce
> the violent crime rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a search for "crime bill" many of the top hits will be about the [Violent Crime Control and Law Enforcement Act of 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violent_Crime_Control_and_Law_Enforcement_Act), which is often referred to as **the** crime bill; as the intro the the wiki article says, it is the largest "crime bill" the the history of the United States.

In general, **a crime bill** is any bill (proposed law) dealing with crime and punishment. Once a *bill* is passed by the legislative body and approved by the executive it is called a *law*, but it is not uncommon to refer to a specific piece of legislation as a *bill* once it has passed into law. This is because the *bill* refers to the group of things that were passed all together in one package, while the *law* refers to the entire [United States Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Code), or a smaller section of it; a single bill can modify, create, or remove many separate sections of the law.

Comment: So, can I say, a bill is a part of a law?

Comment: In the UK, once a bill is passed it is called an "Act of Parliament". or "Act" for short

Comment: @BeautifulMindset a bill becomes a law when it is accepted by the legislative body (depends on the country). It is a proposal.